# Why Are Some Columns "Not In Index" When Creating a New Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new pandas dataframe `displayDF` with 4 columns from the dataframe `finalDF`.

```
displayDF = finalDF[['False','True','RULE ID','RULE NAME']]
```

This command is failing with the error:

```
KeyError: "['False', 'True'] not in index"
```

However, I can see the columns "False" and "True" when I run `finalDF.info()`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 12 entries, 0 to 11
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------            --------------  ----- 
 0   rule_rec_id       12 non-null     object
 1   False             12 non-null     int64 
 2   True              12 non-null     int64 
 3   RULE ID           12 non-null     object
 4   RULE NAME         12 non-null     object
 5   RULE DESCRIPTION  12 non-null     object
dtypes: int64(2), object(4)
memory usage: 672.0+ bytes
```

**Additional Background:**

I created `finalDF` by merging two dataframes (`pivot_stackedPandasDF` and `dfPandaDescriptions`)

```
finalDF = pd.merge(pivot_stackedPandasDF, dfPandaDescriptions, how='left', left_on=['rule_rec_id'], right_on=['RULE ID'])
```

I created `pivot_stackedPandasDF` with this command.

```
pivot_stackedPandasDF = stackedPandasDF.pivot_table(index="rule_rec_id", columns="alert_value", values="count").reset_index()
```

I think the root cause may be in the way I ran the `.pivot_table()` command.

Comment: Is it possible the actual columns in the DataFrame are `True` and `False` (Boolean literals) not `'True'` and `'False'` (Strings)? Try `df[[False, True, 'RULE ID', 'RULE NAME']]`

Comment: Thanks @HenryEcker this is exactly what was going on.